# Multipart/formatted MySQL query problem

Tags: query, mysql, wpdb, sql

I'm creating a plugin and I want to automate the creation of a MySQL Trigger on a table. The problem seems to be that $wpdb->query doesn't appear to accept either multipart statements and/or formatted queries.

If I print and run the following query in phpMyAdmin it returns success. I also noticed if I formatted the query all on 1 line it would still report success but in this case the trigger is NOT created.

```
$wpdb->query(
    "DELIMITER //
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS {$wpdb->get_blog_prefix($site->id)}post_queue_insert//
    CREATE TRIGGER {$wpdb->get_blog_prefix($site->id)}queue_insert BEFORE INSERT ON {$wpdb->get_blog_prefix($site->id)}posts
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO {$wpdb->base_prefix}post_queue (action_id, action_type, action_status, action_timestamp, sync_complete, SITE_ID) VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.post_type, NEW.post_status, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), 0, {$site->id});
    END//
    DELIMITER ;"
);
```

Is there another function I can use or another way to format the query to run successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error I finally figured out a solution using mysqli. I consider it a acceptable solution since the query will only be run on plugin updates.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$sql = "
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS {$wpdb->get_blog_prefix($site->id)}post_queue_insert;
    CREATE TRIGGER {$wpdb->get_blog_prefix($site->id)}post_queue_insert BEFORE INSERT ON {$wpdb->get_blog_prefix($site->id)}posts
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO {$wpdb->base_prefix}post_queue (action_id, action_type, action_status, action_event, action_timestamp, sync_complete, SITE_ID) VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.post_type, NEW.post_status, 'insert', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), 0, {$site->id});
    END;
";

$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
$mysqli->close();
```