# How can I detect right db type?

Tags: database, mysql

I write plugin and use in my code this function: `mysqli_multi_query($wpdb->dbh, $sql_trigger);`. It's not hard to guess that on some hosting systems this function works correctly, but on some it produces the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_multi_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   resource given in
>   /home/blah/blah.com/www/wp-content/plugins/blah/blah.php
>   on line xxx

**Question**: how do I determine which type of database is used on the hosting and then correctly execute my query to the database?

**Notice**: My query to the database contains the following code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `blah_set_current_time_and_date_values`
BEFORE INSERT
ON $table_name
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET NEW.date_visited = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-&Y');
        SET NEW.time_visited = TIME_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s');
END;
```

[That's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127344/wpdb-and-mysql-create-trigger) why I decided to use `mysqli_multi_query()`, since I do not know how else to execute this query. Also, I tried use `$wpdb->query($sql_string);`, but in this case WP returned error: `[Trigger already exists]`. Although it does not exactly exist at that time, I delete it manually using `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS wordpress_rezart_statistics_set_current_time_and_date_values‌​`.

Comment: how is it even remotely **specific** to wordpress?

Comment: @MarkKaplun, Obviously, I'm looking for the most native way to do what in WP.

Comment: since you do not want to use wordpress DB api, I am not sure what kind of "native"  you expect here

Comment: I want, but I can't: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127344/wpdb-and-mysql-create-trigger Also, I tried use `$wpdb->query($sql_string);`, but in this case WP returned error: [Trigger already exists]. Although it does not exactly exist at that time, I delete it manually using `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS wordpress_rezart_statistics_set_current_time_and_date_values`.

Answer (score 1):

`wpdb->dbh` is declared as protected property, you should not even have access to it, unless you are subclassing `wpdb`?

The only *public* property is `wpdb->is_mysql` which is just hardcoded for `true` and meant for detection of non–native database drop–ins.

So overall `wpdb` context is meant to be *internal*, you set up the connection and let it deal with the detail from that point.

I have no experience with triggers in WP context, but it sounds strange for arbitrary query to not just work in `query()` method. I would recommend to get to the bottom of that. It might be that issue is with query or something related and not WP call running it.

Comment: Thx for you answer. 'is declared as protected property, you should not even have access to it, unless you are subclassing wpdb' - I just read about this method there: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/127351/122529

Comment: 'I would recommend to get to the bottom of that. It might be that issue is with query or something related and not WP call running it' - yeah, I just had a hope that someone had already encountered triggers. Right now I do simple - hide_errors() / show_errors() and it works perfectly :)